# Charging two lithium ion batteries in series connection individually

Tags: lithium-ion

Any idea to charge two lithium ion batteries which are connected in series each one gives out 3.7 volts (both to give out 7.4 volts) individually? What's the main idea or circuitry to do the task ?

I will use Microchip MCP73831 chip.

Comment: Why do you want to charge them individually?

Comment: As one of my friends told me that it's not safe & practical to charge li-ion batteries when they are connected in series ..

Comment: Read about [Battery Balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_balancing) and re-educate your friend.

Comment: After reading I promise I will re-educate him, I don't have experience in lithium-ion batteries and I was seeking help.. thanks.. I will read about battery balancing and if I need clarification I will ask you again if you don't mind